# Using regex to get urls with some rules

Tags: php, regex

A string contain many urls, how to get urls start not with `[url]`, and end not with `[/url]`

Example:

> A string contain many urls: https://stackoverflow.com/1 [url]https://stackoverflow.com/2[/url] https://stackoverflow.com/3 [url]https://stackoverflow.com/4[/url], how to get match urls?

In this sample, need only return `https://stackoverflow.com/1` and `https://stackoverflow.com/3`.

Comment: url3 ends with |/url] your question is it only for this example or is it in general  ?

Comment: Only for this example

Comment: @KalaMei do all your URLs start with `http`? See my answer below if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<!\[url\])(?![^\s]+\[\/url\])http[^\s]*`

This will grab the all the URLs not enclosed in the tags you mentioned (`[url]` and `[\url]`). Note that this works for every URL, not just the one you listed (i.e `http://stackoverflow.com`), which I think is what you want. You can see the explanations and live demo for each rule on Regex101 - Link: https://regex101.com/r/wN9aX0/3

Comment: This would also match `http://stackoverflow.com/5[/url]`, i.e. if it doesn't start with [url] but ends with [/url] - not sure if this is OK with the OP.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Oops, that was my bad, my negative lookahead was incorrect, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I will underline only the **regex expression** as it is very important to get the urls. So it will be:

```
 (?!\[url\])\s+\bhttp:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/\d\s+(?<!\[\/url\])
```

you can see the result in this [Url](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gbf) by using the php function `preg_match_all`

but before that let's understand every part of it (you can find this in the same site)

```
(?!\[url\])\s+\bhttp:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/\d\s+(?<!\[\/url\])
```

- **`(?!\[url\])`** Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below

  - **`\[`** matches the character ***[*** literally
  - ***url*** matches the characters url literally (case insensitive)
  - **`\]`** matches the character ***]*** literally

---

- **`\s+`** match any white space character [`\r\n\t\f` ]
  Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **`\b`** assert position at a word boundary (`^\w`|`\w$`|`\W\w`|`\w\W`)
- **http:** matches the characters ***http:*** literally (case sensitive)
- **`\/`** matches the character ***/*** literally
- **`\/`** matches the character ***/*** literally
- **stackoverflow** matches the characters ***stackoverflow*** literally (case sensitive)
- **`.`** matches any character (except newline)
- **com** matches the characters ***com*** literally (case sensitive)
- **/**  matches the character ***/*** literally
- **`\d`** match a digit [0-9]
- **`\s+`** match any white space character [`\r\n\t\f` ]
  Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **`(?<!\[\/url\])`** Negative Lookbehind - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below

  - **`\[`** matches the character ***[*** literally
  - **`\/`** matches the character ***/*** literally
  - **url** matches the characters ***url*** literally (case insensitive)
  - **`\]`** matches the character ***]*** literally

---

Finally you need to use the  php function as follow:

```
preg_match_all("(?!\[url\])\s+\bhttp:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/\d\s+(?<!\[\/url\])", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

`$input_lines` is the variable that holds your string

`$output_array` the arrays that holds the urls

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this regex rule will return all urls (1, 2, 3, 4),
you can see the test at
https://regex101.com/r/tB5lY0/2 or
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0450e2b5d6c5611486be4a380b9adcbaad9bfef2

Comment: You need to use the negative lookbehind an lookahead ! I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated pattern and probably won't work for all cases, but will work for most. If it doesn't work in a case you want it to work, I could tweak it further:

```
(?<!(\[url\]))[\s.:]((http|https)(:\/\/))?([[:alnum:]\-_]*)(([\.])([[:alnum:]\-_]*)){1,}([\/]([[:alnum:]\-_]*))*[.:;\s]((?!\[\/url\]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```
var patt =/(?:\bhttp:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/\d{1,})(?!\[\/url\])/;
```

Example :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
         <script>
             var patt =/(?:\bhttp:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/\d{1,})(?!\[\/url\])/;
             var str = "http://stackoverflow.com/2";
             if(patt.test(str))
                 alert("Valid");
             else
                 alert("Invalid");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```